# Can't figure out file path to download to local machine from AWS though nodejs server

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I feel stupid. I'm trying create a function, to download files from my AWS S3  bucket to the client pc using nodeJS. The filePath variable works perfectly when I run the server on localhost, but when the project is uploaded I get Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open './data/'

On localhost it download the documents to the data directory in my project. I would like to to download to the downloads directory on the client pc.

I have no idea how to specify a file path to a local directory. I've tried all sorts of paths such as ./d/Users/username/Desktop, same error each time.

```
 AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "id",
    secretAccessKey: "key"
});

const filePath = './data/'+req.body.file;
const bucketName =  'bucket';
const key =req.body.key;
var s3 = new AWS.S3();


const downloadFile = (filePath, bucketName, key) => {

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: key
    }

    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)

        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data.Body)
        console.log(`${filePath} has been created!`);
        res.send("File Downloaded");
    })
}

downloadFile(filePath, bucketName, key)
});
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't find any specific examples online. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This code works on the server side, as you can download files to ur project directory. But download files to client side is a different story

Comment: @SwordW Thanks for the quick reply. Could you elaborate? What should I be researching? One of the hardest parts of learning to code is actually figuring out what to search for :-) Thanks

Comment: Sorry just saw it now. I could be wrong, but I don't think you can have direct access to client pc via browser.

Comment: @SwordW thanks for the follow up, I now realise it's a multi step process